# How to get the edge coordinate of an ellipse in Javascript at a specific degree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, geometry, ellipse

I am trying to determine the edges of an ellipse SVG in Javascript. What i have now is the center coordinate of the ellipse, the rectangle coordinates over it, and the top/left/right/bottom edges of the ellipse, but how can i determine the A,B,C,D point coordinates of an ellipse in Javascript?

[image]

Comment: Hope this is 2D... if you mean by specific degree the diagonal then use parametric ellipse equation with `45,135,225,315` degrees. If you really mean any angle then compute coordinate aligned with bigger semi axis and compute the other one from ellipse equation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rational parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) of an ellipse might help:

```js
var e = document.querySelector('ellipse'),
  p = document.querySelector('circle');

var rx = +e.getAttribute('rx'),
  ry = +e.getAttribute('ry');

var angle = 0;
const spin = () => {
    angle *= angle !== 360;
    var t = Math.tan(angle++ / 360 * Math.PI);
    var px = rx * (1 - t ** 2) / (1 + t ** 2),
        py = ry * 2 * t / (1 + t ** 2);
    p.setAttribute('cx', px);
    p.setAttribute('cy', py);
    requestAnimationFrame(spin)
}

requestAnimationFrame(spin)
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-105 -55 210 110" height="200" width="400">
<ellipse stroke="#000" fill="#fff" cx="0" cy="0" rx="100" ry="50"/>
<circle fill="red" r="3"/>
</svg>
```

So for your points a, b, c, d:

```js
var e = document.querySelector('ellipse'),
  a = document.querySelector('#a'),
  b = document.querySelector('#b'),
  c = document.querySelector('#c'),
  d = document.querySelector('#d');

var rx = +e.getAttribute('rx'),
  ry = +e.getAttribute('ry');

[a, b, c, d].forEach((p, i) => {
    var t = Math.tan(i * Math.PI / 4 + Math.atan(2 * ry / rx) / 2);
    var px = rx * (1 - t ** 2) / (1 + t ** 2),
        py = ry * 2 * t / (1 + t ** 2);
    console.log(p.id + '(' + px + ', ' + py + ')');
    p.setAttribute('cx', px);
    p.setAttribute('cy', py);
})
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-105 -55 210 110" height="200" width="400">
<rect stroke="#000" fill="#fff" x="-100" y="-50" width="200" height="100"/>
<path stroke="#000" d="M-100-50L100 50zM-100 50L100-50z"/>
<ellipse stroke="#000" fill="none" cx="0" cy="0" rx="100" ry="50"/>
<circle id="a" fill="red" r="3"/>
<circle id="b" fill="red" r="3"/>
<circle id="d" fill="red" r="3"/>
<circle id="c" fill="red" r="3"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate for example the point `A` with coordinates `A.x, A.y`. To this end, let's assume first that the center `O` of the ellipse has coordinates `0, 0`. To get the general case at the end, the final result will be just shifted by `O.x, O.y`.

Now, the line connecting points `O` and `R2` is described by

```
y = (R2.y / R2.x) * x
```

To simplify the notation below, let's denote `a := R2.y / R2.x`. The ellipse itself is defined as a set of points which satisfy:

```
(y/yd)**2 + (x/xd)**2 = 1
```

So in order to get the intersection, we can just substitute the first equation into the second one. This yields:

```
x**2 * ( (a/yd)**2 + 1/xd**2 ) = 1
```

thus (since the intersection point is in the first quadrant, we know that `x` has a positive sign):

```
x = 1 / Math.sqrt( (a/yd)**2 + 1/xd**2 )
y = a * x
```

Finally, to address non-zero offset of the center of the ellipse, we can just add the corresponding offset. Therefore:

```
x = O.x + 1 / Math.sqrt( (a/yd)**2 + 1/xd**2 )
y = O.y + a * x
```